# How do I take text from a txt file and turn them into instance variables for an object?

Tags: java, arrays, methods, project, instance-variables

I am supposed to read a text file containing a list of movie/series and for each line of the text file I have to create a new Media object (either a movie or series as subclasses). I've already created a method that reads the text file and creates an array of object for each line. But my question is how do I take the words from the text in the text file and turn them into the instance variables for the new object I have created.

the Media Class's and subclasses's constructor and Variables are as follows:

```
// Media Class Variable and constructor
    protected String genre;
    protected String year;
    protected float rating;
    protected String Title;

    public Media(String genre, String year, float rating, String title) {
        this.genre = genre;
        this.year = year;
        this.rating = rating;
        Title = title;

// Movie subclass constructor and variables
    private int lengthHr;
    private int lengthMin;

public Movie(String genre, String year, float rating, String title,int lengthH,int lengthM) {
        super(genre, year, rating, title);

    }
```

Here is how i read the file.

```
// Reads file line by line and increments line count to create a new array of media object.. probably wrong.

public  List<String> readFile() throws Exception{

String line;
int numLines=0;

List<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path));
    while((line=br.readLine())!=null){
        lines.add(line);
        numLines++;
    }

br.close();
Media[] media = new Media[numLines];
return lines;
}
```

Based on these lines from the text file:

Begin Text:

[!Women Art Revolution (2010) |   3 stars, 1hr 22m

1 Cheerleader Camp (2010) |   3 stars, 1hr 35m

$5 a Day (2008) |   3.4 stars, 1hr 37m

'night, Mother (1986) |   3.7 stars, 1hr 36m

'Til Death (2006-2009) |   3.7 stars, 4 Seasons]

End Text:

How am i supposed to tell my Array of media Objects
to say take this text and turn it into say: this.

```
Media[0] = new Movie("Movie","2010",3.0,"Woman Art Revolution",1,22);
```

The first thought that comes to mind is splitting but i'm not sure of the best way to handle that, and please forgive the lack of higher quality examples... I don't have a lot of work done on this yet. And any helpful suggestions would help me finish this project a lot sooner thank you.

Do note that there are a lot more lines of text beyond this Sample and if you can think of a quicker way to create these objects would be appreciated also.

Comment: What language? It should be one of the tags.

Comment: Sorry I litterally just signed up for this site the language is Java i updated the tags accordingly.

Comment: welcome to Stack Overflow. I thought it was Java, but some sort of dot net language also looked possible.

Comment: Read the text, parse it and feed the data to your `Movie` class. What specific part is a problem?

Comment: Every line follows the same pattern: title, followed by year between parentheses, followed by `|` separator, followed by rating, followed by the word *stars*, followed by duration. So using String's indexOf, substring() and lastIndexOf() methods, you could easily implement a parsing algorithm.

Comment: @ JB Nizet oh okay thank you.